# Default language and template style on multilingual JOOMLA website

Tags: templates, joomla, multilingual

lately i realised that i have a problem with my website. i run it almost 5 years now on joomla CMS.
I always keep it updated and do my best in order to be in good condition.

Anyway, till lately i had this configuration:
2 installed languages, Greek (default) and English. 2 template styles for Revibe template(joomshaper.com), first, let's say A, default for all pages and second, let's say B, default for English pages. These 2 styles had different main menus. One Greek on A style and one English menu on B style(Greek menu items and English menu items). This configuration run smoothly as i said till lately. When someone asked about the Greek section of my website he could see a Greek menu and he asked about English menu he could see an English one.

So i just realised, from now on, that if someone visit the English part there is no menu at all! i first tried to change my menu in English style, from template's option, but this made no difference. It was like the English style wasn't there. Then i copied all english menu items of my English menu in the Greek menu and things fixed. i found the solution to the problem, a problem which, as i said, i hadn't before.

But I made some other tries to find out what's the cause. i found that if i change my website's default language, from Greek to English, the English template style is working, and vice versa. This wasn't the way that things worked before. Did anything changed lately on joomla updates?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the preferable template at the equivalent menu items?

e.g: Home (en-GB) Beez3 , Αρχική (el-GR) protostar

hint: Template Styles from Details panel in edit menu...